# Who should own the state value of an item?

Tags: flux, redux

My flux app displays a list locations. When user clicks on a location, it becomes 'active'. There can be only one active location at a time.

Should the state of location be a property of the location itself (e.g. `location.active`) or should it be part of the global state, e.g. `activeLocationId`?

Comment: I'd let a store handle the active location: let that be the 'source of truth'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written several variations of the app. It became obvious that `active` is not a property of the item itself (`location` in this case), but is the property of the UI (`activeLocationId`).

Some benefits:

- Single source of truth (You will not end up accidentally with two active locations).
- It is not affected if new location list is loaded (This is regardless of wether the new list includes the active location or not).
- Makes it easy to find the active location ID.